# Google Compute Engine - Instance Shutdown request deleting and recreating instance deleting all data

Tags: centos7, google-compute-engine, couchbase

I am new to GCS, I created a Compute Engine Instance via Instance Group. and installed Couchbase Server and Node JS on them. After four five days of working I tried to shutdown my instances. As I was fire shutdown request the instance gives success message and then starts coming up again. In the action Log I see shutdown request with my username and then I see Instance delete and re-create actions without any username details.

I lost all the data installed and created on the machine. Please help me know if that is a normal behavior? Or there is any specific way to shut down instances?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you were using the [managed instance group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances) which uses instance template to create the instances in the group. If that's the case, you can use a custom image to create an instance template. You can follow the steps below:

1. Create GCE instance install and configure Couchbase and Node JS.
2. Create an [image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images) from your boot disk.
3. Create the instance template for your manage instance group using this 
   custom image.
4. You can create the managed instance group using this template.

Once done all new instance create in your instance group will have the Couchbase and Node JS installed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not as familiar with GCS, but it sounds like you are using local storage. What I would call ephemeral storage. Does GCS have anything like a network storage you can create and you can mount to the instance for Couchbase to be installed on? I have to think it does. I know AWS and Azure have that. That is how you will make sure that when you throw an instance away, the storage is saved to be reattached to a new instance.

All that said, if you were running a cluster, you could just take the hit of the node being gone. The either manually or programmatically, spin up a new compute instance, install Couchbase, add it to the cluster and rebalance. Then you are good.